# History of solving linear equations with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, math-history

I'm solving linear equations with matrices right now and I wonder, how did it start.

Who, how, why came to idea that such kind of equations could be solved with matrices? What was first: matrix or linear equation? How did they found each other?

Will be glad, if anybody is able to answer my question.

Comment: It is interesting to note that the Chinese knew about Gaussian elimination way before Gauss started to think about his algorithm. See [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=V7mxZqjs5yUC&pg=PA89) for instance.

Comment: This is information may be incorrect at times, I think I got it from E.T.Bell's *Men of Mathematics* and an (french) exercice book. Gauss already used 3 by 3 arrays of numbers to describe maps, and I think his student Eisenstein introduced the notation $\frac{1}{S}$ to denote the inverse of $S$, but that notation was later abandoned.

Comment: You can also have a look at [this](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/mawrld-27-prev.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links: https://web.archive.org/web/20170628165531/https://ualr.edu/lasmoller/matrices.html and https://web.archive.org/web/20120910034016/https://darkwing.uoregon.edu/~vitulli/441.sp04/LinAlgHistory.html have some info on this :)

Comment: Lissa, maybe you could let us know what you find unclear in those references and then we could help.

Comment: Both links are broken :( Could you update them ?

Comment: Fortunately I found them on Wayback machine